# What does the 'with' keyword in node.js stand for?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking at the following node.js code:

```
Chrome(function (chrome) {
    with (chrome) {
        on('Network.requestWillBeSent', function (message) {
            console.log(message.request.url);
        });
        on('Page.loadEventFired', close);
        Network.enable();
        Page.enable();
        Page.navigate({'url': 'https://github.com'});
    }
}).on('error', function () {
    console.error('Cannot connect to Chrome');
});
```

which is taken from [here](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface). My question is what is the "with" keyword where it says "with (chrome)" I can't find it in the api.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with (Note that using `with` is not recommended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't stand for anything, it means "with" in the sense of the English word.

It isn't part of the Node API, it is core JavaScript.

See [the EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.10) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

> Adds the given object to the scope chain used when evaluating the statement. The parentheses around object are required.

It basically means that for any variable, after checking for a local variable and before checking the default object (which would be `window` is this was client side JS in a webpage) for a property of that name, it will check the object in `chrome` for a property of that name.

Comment: It should be noted that use of `with` is universally frowned upon as it tends to make code less understandable.

Comment: Also, *with* statements [*aren't allowed*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.10.1) in strict mode code.